# django-rest-framework : setting per user permissions

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have REST api created using DRF 3.0.1. If I use the permission class **`rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated`**, any authenticated user can perform GET, POST, etc. actions for any user as long he has a valid token.

I want to set per user permissions in that an admin user can see and update all users' data but any non-admin user should only be able to see and update only his data.

From the examples I have seen so far, it seems like **`rest_framework.permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions`** is the class I need to use. However, the examples use Class Based Views.

I have used Function Based Views in my code. Is it possible to implement this using function based views? Doing `queryset = <Model>.objects.non()` as suggested in [DRF doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions) doesn't help. It complains `Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not have .model or .queryset property.`

Is there a way I can do this without moving from FBVs to CBVs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `api_view` decorator of DRF?

if so, you might find `rest_framework.decorators.permission_classes` useful.

`@permission_classes([SomePermission])`

Comment: Perfect! It took me a while to understand permission but it's really amazing. Thank you!