# Django Rest Framework User and UserRole and Permission Handling using Token Authentication

Tags: django, authentication, permissions, django-rest-framework

I am newbie to **Django Rest Framework**. I googled a lot and stuck on How to set **User Role** to **User** and strict to **Permission**.

My question is very basic but I don't know how to do it.

I want to create 2 types of Users:

1) **Admin** (Full Access)

2) **Normal User** (Limited Access)

I found some links but still on getting what to do:
[Django rest-framework per action permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313314/django-rest-framework-per-action-permission)
[django-rest-framework : setting per user permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072756/django-rest-framework-setting-per-user-permissions)

Comment: do you user django user model?

Comment: yes. I want to use django User Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can separate users by `is_staff` property and use, standart rest permission [isadminuser](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isadminuser), for test you try this simple view

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

Comment: Thanks Brown. Actually, my requirement is more than just admin and user role. I can have 3 users. All have different roles and permission. Any help on it ?

Comment: you can use [custom-permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) for your own way